# Detached DB showing up in back-up history

Tags: sql-server, backup

I found a script to show me the databases that are not backed-up in the last 24 hours: [Script to retrieve SQL Server database backup history and no backups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/)

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date, 
DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), 
GETDATE()) AS  [Backup Age (Hours)] 
FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset 
WHERE     msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'D'  
GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
HAVING      
(MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - 24,     GETDATE()))  
 UNION  
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server,  
 master.dbo.sysdatabases.NAME AS database_name,  
 NULL AS [Last Data Backup Date],  
 9999 AS [Backup Age (Hours)]  
 FROM 
 master.dbo.sysdatabases LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
 ON master.dbo.sysdatabases.name  = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
 WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name IS NULL 
 AND  master.dbo.sysdatabases.name <> 'tempdb' 
 ORDER BY  
 msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
```

The result shows me the DB that no logner exists. These are the DB that i have deleted/detached a while back. Why are these showing up?

[image: DBs that are deleted]

Comment: Have you dropped the database or detached it, be specific ? And while dropping the database did you selected `Delete backup and restore history` ?. If not the history would be there

Comment: I dont remember. Is there any way to find out?

Answer (score 2):

When you use Delete Database from modern versions of Management Studio, it asks whether you want to delete the backup history for this database in MSDB. The reason that a deleted database is showing in your query is simply because backup history exists for it - in MSDB.

I adjusted your query by joining backupset to sysdatabases, so it excludes databases that do not exist at the moment you run the query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date, 
DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date), 
GETDATE()) AS  [Backup Age (Hours)] 
FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset 
inner join master.dbo.sysdatabases
on msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name=master.dbo.sysdatabases.name
WHERE     msdb.dbo.backupset.type = 'D'  
GROUP BY msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
HAVING      
(MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) < DATEADD(hh, - 24,     GETDATE()))  
 UNION  
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server,  
 master.dbo.sysdatabases.NAME AS database_name,  
 NULL AS [Last Data Backup Date],  
 9999 AS [Backup Age (Hours)]  
 FROM 
 master.dbo.sysdatabases LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
 ON master.dbo.sysdatabases.name  = msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name 
 WHERE msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name IS NULL 
 AND  master.dbo.sysdatabases.name <> 'tempdb' 
 ORDER BY  
 msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name
```

Comment: Please use sys.databases - sysdatabases is deprecated and only present for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont remember. Is there any way to find out.

When you detach database you dont delete it you just remove it from SQL Server instance. The mdf and ldf files would be present at location where it was before, if you have not deleted the files. Detaching a database removes it from the instance of SQL Server but leaves the database intact within its data files and transaction log files. [This link](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10379.find-detached-databases) has code which can be used to find which database is not attached to SQL Server. Or you can simply go to windows serach functionality and search *.mdf and if you can see your database name listed it was detached.

> The result shows me the DB that no logner exists. These are the DB that i have deleted/detached a while back. Why are these showing up?

When you delete/drop a database using SSMS GUI and while doing so you select `Delete backup and restore history` SQL Server will remove backup history of that database. What it does internally is it will run a system stored procedure called [sp_delete_database_backuphistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178645.aspx) this stored procedure will delete backup information about the specified database from the system tables.

Now if you still see the information you can execute the stored procedure and remove backup information related to this specific database. For example below command will remove the information

```
sp_delete_database_backuphistory  'database_name'
```